# Apply a material to a heirarchy

Tags: materials, outliner

I have an imported model with a hierarchy of objects.
Expanding to the tip of one branch looks like:
[image]

I'd like to be pick materials for sections of the hierarchy (e.g. by top level parents). But it seems that I can't apply a material to an Empty, and I presume in Blender that applying a material to a parent does not act on the material of the child.

What is the best way to go about this?

Further notes:

- The meshes already have materials from the import, I'd need to override these (can just delete the materials)
- I could do with python if the interface doesn't handle this use case
- Right click and 'Select hierarchy' gets me half-way there. But since this selects the Empty's also, the material tab is still hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Material Utils" addon, bundled with Blender. It can reassign material to all selected objects at once

More details here: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Materials_Utils

Comment: Could you please expand on this answer.

Comment: Just install addon, select all objects you wish to change (via outliner or right in scene), press Shift-q -> Assign Material -> Select material and you are done. All selected objects will have this material reassigned


Addon description: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Materials_Utils

Comment: @IPv6 you could update your answer with your link!